# Delete prefab from the screen, Unity AR Foundation programming in C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

Everything is set up the way it should, by now. This code is attached to the prefab itself, working nicely. I just want to know how to delete the prefab when the image is lost, so I can do a good transition to another prefab (correspondent to another image that is being tracked). I don't know if I should use a timer or if there is other way. I would like it to be as smooth as possible. Any help is appreciated.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Events;
using UnityEngine.XR.ARFoundation;
using UnityEngine.XR.ARSubsystems;
 
public class ImageTracking2 : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string ReferenceImageName;
    private ARTrackedImageManager _TrackedImageManager;
 
    private void Awake()
    {
        _TrackedImageManager = FindObjectOfType<ARTrackedImageManager>();
    }
 
    private void OnEnable()
    {
        if (_TrackedImageManager != null)
        {
            _TrackedImageManager.trackedImagesChanged += OnTrackedImagesChanged;
        }
    }
 
    private void OnDisable()
    {
        if (_TrackedImageManager != null)
        {
            _TrackedImageManager.trackedImagesChanged -= OnTrackedImagesChanged;
        }
    }
 
    private void OnTrackedImagesChanged(ARTrackedImagesChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var trackedImage in e.added)
        {
            Debug.Log($"Tracked image detected: {trackedImage.referenceImage.name} with size: {trackedImage.size}");
        }
 
        UpdateTrackedImages(e.added);
        UpdateTrackedImages(e.updated);
    }
 
    private void UpdateTrackedImages(IEnumerable<ARTrackedImage> trackedImages)
    {
        // If the same image (ReferenceImageName)
        var trackedImage =
            trackedImages.FirstOrDefault(x => x.referenceImage.name == ReferenceImageName);
        if (trackedImage == null)
        {
            return;
        }
     
        if (trackedImage.trackingState != TrackingState.None)
        {
            var trackedImageTransform = trackedImage.transform;
            transform.SetPositionAndRotation(trackedImageTransform.position, trackedImageTransform.rotation);  
        }
    }
}
```

This is my first post, I hope that the organization is correct. The code the way it is above is keeping the prefab in the screen, sometimes in randon places.If I can kill it when the image is lost, I will be able to make the transition to the other images better. Pleas, if you can, show me the code. I'm still learning C#, basically started this Unity problem with no experience at all.